# How to make part of the page not scrollable (without overlaps on the mobile view)

Tags: javascript, html, css

the webpage I'm creating is mainly divided in two divs vertically, and I want only the right side of the page (div with id #rightside) to be scrollable.

I've managed to achieve this by setting their values for z-index, position, top, left, right, and so on, but the problem is that the right side of the content (#rightside) starts to overlap on top of the left side of the content (#leftside) upon resizing the window down to a smaller, mobile device view.

How do I stop #rightside from covering the #leftside?

Below is part of the html:

```
<div class="jumbotron">      
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5" id="leftside">
            <h1>H1 Title</h1>
            <p class="roles">roles</p>
            <img src="">
            <p class="fulldescription">description text</p>
            <p class="fulldescription">description text</p>
            <img src="" class="circleIcon">
        </div> <!-- end of leftside -->


        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7" id="rightside">
            <img src="" width="1127" class="scaling">
            <img src="" width="1127" class="scaling">
        </div> <!-- end of rightside -->

   </div> <!-- end of the main row -->
</div> <!-- end of the main jumbotron -->
```

Below is part of css:

```
#leftside{
    margin-top: 12px;
    height:auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 50px 90px 0px 100px; /*top right bottom left*/

    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left:15px;

}

#rightside{
    margin-top: 12px;
    height:auto;    
    background:#FCF;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;

    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;

}
```

EDIT: To visually make it easier to understand, this is the kind of website that I'm trying to create. [example site](http://madebypfd.com/website-design-and-photography-for-grays-bath)

Upon resizing the window down to a mobile view, the right side of the content is placed below the left side of the content. But what I'm getting now is that the right side content is placed on top of the left side content, covering it completely.

Comment: `top: 50;` and `left:15;` should have units e.g. `top: 50px;` and `left:15px;` to be syntactically ok. (you could use others such as `em` or even `%` ...

Comment: Unless you have seriously unique content, the odds of a side-by-side layout on a phone in portrait mode being a decent solution are quite slim. Similarly, using stuff that cannot be scrolled away on a small screen is very unproductive for the user ...  The solution then lies in "responsive design" and use an entirely different layout on narrow screens.

Comment: I added in some more info to make it clearer what I'm trying to achieve.